# How do I select the last of a certain number of consecutive elements of the same class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am currently trying to colour the border of each heading a different colour in the rainbow, such that this HTML would have the first heading styled `maroon`, second `orange`, third `olive`:

```
<h2 class="rh">Heading 1</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h2 class="rh">Heading 2</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h2 class="rh">Heading 3</h2>
<p>Text</p>
```

My current CSS is this. However, this is really inefficent. Is there a better way?

```
.rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid maroon;
}
.rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid olive;
}
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid navy;
}
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh,
.rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh ~ .rh {
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen any CSS that looked quite like that!

Comment: You can just show us the HTML and tell us what you want to do instead.

Comment: Your title says "consecutive elements of the same class". Wouldn't that obviate the need for `~` when you can just use `+` instead?

Comment: Not exactly, my title was poorly worded. Essentially, I have some html like this: `<h2 class="rh">Heading 1</h2><p>Text</p><h2 class="rh">Heading 2</h2><p>Text</p>`, and I want each heading to be the next colour in the rainbow.

Comment: Yes, they do. I could effectively do `<div class="r"><h2>heading</h2><p>text</p>...</div>`

Comment: In that case @Wrikken's answer works, assuming you don't need to support IE7 and IE8...

Comment: Score :). Indeed, a `nth-of-type` would then work, with the same problem as the original answer: MSIE needs to be >= 9.

Comment: @Wrikken: Edit your answer anyway ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: OK, just this once :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit #a_lot:**

as we've established in the comments it the classname is not needed, we can use for most major browsers, and MSIE >=9:

```
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+1){
    border-bottom: 2px solid maroon;
}
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+2){
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+3){
    border-bottom: 2px solid olive;
}
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+4){
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+5){
    border-bottom: 2px solid navy;
}
.r > h2:nth-of-type(6n+6){
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}
```

---

<del>The following answer is wrong, but kept as a reference as to why it's wrong: something like `p.classname:nth-of-type(3n)` selects the paragraphs which are *both* the 3rd `p` element *and* have the class `classname`, rather then *every 3rd `p` which has class `classname`* as I would've expected.</del>

---

<del>In the far away future, you can use [`nth-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype), around the point when MSIE 9 is commonly used and MSIE6/7/8 are retired. So, for now: you're out of lock.</del>

Comment: Not really... `:nth-of-type()` doesn't apply to class, it applies to type. If there are other children of the same type without the class, the styles won't apply properly.

Comment: I stand corrected indeed: a quick test shows indeed that something like `p.classname:nth-of-type(3n)` selects the paragraphs which are _both_ the 3rd `p` element _and_ have the class `classname`, rather then _every 3rd `p` which has class `classname`_ as I would've expected. I'll leave this answer here just as a reference as to why this solution is wrong.

Comment: Yeah... I found this out the hard way a while ago, and had to rewrite this answer (see its revisions) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3615559/revisions

Comment: Thanks! This solution works perfectly! (http://pickeringsteam.com/attractions.shtml)